# Programmatically add a document to Delve favourites

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, delve

W have a requirement to pin a document that is stored in a SharePoint Online document library to the current user's Delve Favourites. Is there a way to do this with JavaScript?

I've found some undocumented APIs to pin the document to Delve Boards, but I need a way to pin the document to Delve Favourites.

Thanks